# Single Excel chart showing data from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, charts

Okay, so I have the following set-up:

I have a single Excel workbook with 4 sheets in it.
Each sheet represents one quarter of a year, containing 4 columns:

1. Total A
2. Fraction of A
3. Total B
4. Fraction of B

I tried creating a fifth sheet that draws data from each of the four sheets. I therefore have 4 rows in that sheet that each represents a quarter of a year, and the aforementioned 4 columns.
I want to create a single graph that shows the development of each of the 4 columns throughout each quarter of a year.

Is this even possible with Excel (2013)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'll need to edit data in a graph. You could start with a new graph on sheet 5. Right-click on the blank graph and choose "Select Data...".

From there you can easily add data from the other sheets.